# closest approximation to finite dimensional subspace

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I want to prove that if $X$ is a normed space, $A$ is some finite dimensional subspace of $X$, and $x \in X/A$, then there is some $y\in A$ such that $d(x,A) = \|x - y\|$.

I am familiar with this theorem if $X$ is a Hilbert space. How can I utilize the fact that $A$ is finite dimensional to prove it for a general normed space $X$?

Comment: Are those real/complex vector spaces? Or is the field some other field?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: When someone mentions normed spaces, I usually assume that they mean real or complex spaces. Don't you? (In fact, I don't recall ever having heard about a normed space over any other field.)

Comment: @tomasz: I hardly ever consider normed spaces. But it could just as well be a subfield of the real numbers, or the complex numbers. At some point I started treating $p$-adic norms as "norms" as well, and in fact any $F$-norm for a valued field $F$ is a norm. Why would I want to be trapped in the real numbers? :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Is there a theory of vector spaces over valued fields? I've recently attended a reading course on model theory of valued fields, but no one mentioned anything of the sort (pardon the pun ;) ).

Comment: @tomasz: I am fairly certain there there are $p$-adic norms, as for the general case - I don't know. But why would I want to be trapped in the present? :-)

Comment: real/complex. I would be satisfied also for reals only :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point is that finite-dimensional real/complex normed vector spaces are locally compact. So every bounded sequence has a converging subsequence.

So take a sequence $a_n$ in $A$ such that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \|x-a_n\|=d(x,A).
$$

Check that $a_n$ is bounded.

Extract a susbsequence $a_{n_k}$ which converges to $y$.

Since $A$ is a finite-dimensional space, it is complete (that's a second key fact here), hence closed in $X$. So $y$ belongs to $A$.

Finally
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow+\infty}\|x-a_{n_k}\|=\|x-y\|=d(x,A).
$$

Comment: Thanks. How would I show that finite-dimensional normed spaces are locally compact? Is it enough to say that it is isomorphic to R^n (if dealing with reals) and since R^n is locally compact, it is too? Even if this argument works, I don't like it somehow :P How can we show that a finite-dimensional space is locally compact?

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat Almost. You can use that all norms are equivalent on a finite-dimensional space (this follows for instance from the fact the unit sphere is compact with respect to the Euclidean norm, so that's not circular). [See this link](http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/ProofThatAllNormsOnFiniteVectorSpaceAreEquivalent.html). Then the topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ Euclidean is the same as the one induced by an arbitrary norm.

Comment: @julien But the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is circular when $n = 2$. (Sorry to be flippant, but it was too tempting :-).

Comment: @RobArthan Ah! That was funny!

Answer (score 1):

Choose $y \in A^C$, and let $\alpha = \inf_{a \in A} \|a-y\|$. Choose $a_n \in A$ such that $\lim_n \|a_n-y\| = \alpha$. Hence $a_n$ is bounded, and since $A$ is finite dimensional, $a_n$ converges to some $\hat{a} \in A$ over some subsequence. It is clear that $\|\hat{a}-y\| = \alpha$.